# Given an array of increasing integers: How do you return a range for every three or more consecutive integers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ruby

Given the array (list) of integers below, I am looking to extract each integer and if three or more integers ascend consecutively, I want to replace the middle integers with a "-" to represent a range. And then lastly return values as a string.

For example, the first 7 integers from list: `-6, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 3`
Would become `'-6,-3-1,3'`
Because there is more than three consecutive integers from -3 to 1.

Ultimately, `solution(list)` should return the following string: `"-6,-3-1,3-5,7-11,14,15,17-20"`

In its present form it returns the following string: `"-6,-3,-2,-1,0,1,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,14,15,17,18,19,20"`
Which is simply the array converted into a string.

```
var list = [-6, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20];
solution(list);

function solution(list) {
    final = [];
    range = [];
    while (list.length > 0) {
        take = list.splice(0,1);
        range.push(take); 
        n = 1;
        while (take+n === list[0]) {
            a = list.splice(0,1); 
            range.push(a);
            n++;
        }
        if (range.length >= 3) {
            min = Math.min(range).toString();
            max = Math.max(range).toString();
            final.push(min + "-" + max); 
            range.length = 0;
        } else if (range.length === 2) {
            final.push(range[0].toString());
            final.push(range[1].toString());
            range.length = 0;
        } else if (range.length === 1) {
            final.push(range[0].toString());
            range.length = 0;
        }
    }
    return final.join(",");
}
```

However, I was able to get the desired result successfully in Ruby:

```
list = [-6, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20]

def solution(list)
    final = []
    range = []
    while (list.length > 0) do
        take = list.shift
        range << take 
        n = 1
        while (take+n == list[0]) do
            a = list.slice!(0) 
            range << a
            n +=1
        end
        if (range.length >= 3)
            final << (range.min.to_s + "-" + range.max.to_s) 
            range = []
        elsif (range.length == 2)
            final << range[0]
            final << range[1]
            range = []
        elsif (range.length == 1)
            final << range[0].to_s
            range = []
        end
    end
    return final.join(",")
end
```

My approach in Ruby is almost identical that of my JavaScript.  So, if I was wondering if someone could:

1) Explain why this approach works with Ruby, but not Javascript.  Please feel free to inform me even if it is a simple syntax error on my part.

2) How I could possibly go about extracting the integers and returning the correct ranges in JavaScript?

Your help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: You can use breakpoints/trace in Chrome dev tool to trace each step/variables as the program runs.

Comment: What would `-3, -2, -1` return? Something like `-3--1`?

Comment: @sagarpandya82: Yes.  Always in ascending order.

Comment: @Stefan:  I have not tested an only negative integer range yet.  But I would have to say, yes that would be ideal.

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer?

Comment: The Ruby solution doesn't have to be long-winded: `list.chunk_while { |b,a| a == b + 1 }.map { |a| a.length >= 3 ? [ a[0], a[-1] ].join('-') : a }.join(',')` works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splice returns an array, you have to take the first item from returned array

```
take = list.splice(0,1)[0];
```

> Also note that [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) (`take = list.shift()`) is a better candidate for this operation.

Math.min doesn't accept arrays, you can use a workaround with apply/call

```
Math.min.apply(null,range);
```

> In ES6 this can be done as `Math.min(...range)` using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

It is better to clear an array by assigning to a new array.

```
range = [];
```

I obviously prefer the functional and declarative method by @ninasholz This is just to explain *why my code didn't work*

```js
var list = [-6, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20];
console.log(solution(list));

function solution(list) {
  final = [];
  range = [];
  while (list.length > 0) {
         //splice returns array take first item
        take = list.splice(0,1)[0];
        range.push(take); 
        n = 1;
        while (take + n === list[0]) {
              a = list.splice(0,1)[0]; 
              range.push(a);
              n++;
        }
        console.log(range);
        if (range.length >= 3) {
        //Math.min doesnt accept arrays
           min = Math.min.apply(null,range);
           max = Math.max.apply(null,range);
           final.push(min + "-" + max); 
           range = [];
        } else if (range.length === 2) {
                  final.push(range[0]);
                  final.push(range[1]);
                  range = [];
        } else if (range.length === 1) {
                  final.push(range[0]);
                  range = [];
        }
  }
  return final.join(",");
}
```

Comment: I was unaware Math.min(); didn't accept arrays.  Thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: @moveson The question is why the ruby code ported to javascript didn't work, as I understand it. ninasholz has a better answer in my opinion :) Again people prefer to keep code that they *understand*

Comment: @sabithpocker: yep, that indeed was the question :)

Comment: @moveson: also, there's no ruby in this answer :)

Comment: Note that `list.splice(0,1)[0];` is similar to `list.shift()`. Also, in es6, you can use the spread syntax instead of having to call `apply` like so: `Math.min(...range)`

Comment: @user3297291 This answer only points out *why it didn't work* NinaSholz already has a wonderful solution here.

Comment: I know, but since this is the accepted answer and it shows `.splice(0, 1)[0]` in the first paragraph, I figured it might be nice to place a foot note saying that there are more easy fixes ;) Additionally, sometimes the OP learns more from an in depth analysis of their own code than a complete copy-pasteable replacement, so I think there's definitely value in this answer!

Comment: I do agree, I'll edit to add those markers. Again, thank you for the sugesstion.

Comment: @user3297291 Its there now :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a better ruby solution:

```
list = [-6, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20]

stringified = list.chunk_while{|a, b| a == b - 1}.map do |seq|
#                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the core of the solution
  if seq.length > 2 # long enough sequence
    "#{seq.first}-#{seq.last}"
  else
    seq
  end
end.join(', ')

stringified # => "-6, -3-1, 3-5, 7-11, 14, 15, 17-20"
```

This should also be a hint for your javascript implementation. Separate concerns as much as possible. Chunking, stringifying, turning a sequence into a range-like string: these all should be separate pieces of code. If they're not all tangled together, they're much easier to reason about.

Comment: The documentation for [`chunk_while`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) contains a similar example :)

Comment: @Stefan: ooh, it does, indeed. :)

Comment: Thanks Sergio.  Perhaps, if I refactored my Ruby code first, the solution might have to me for JavaScript.

Comment: This is the best answer. Note that the OP's specified result doesn't include spaces between the groups. Obviously that's easily fixed.

Comment: The power of ruby in this regard :)

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript, you could use a three pass approach, first for getting the grouped ranges, then get the ranges in an array and later join the whole array.

```js
var array = [-6, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20],
    result = array
        .reduce(function (r, a) {
            var last = r[r.length - 1];
            if (last && last[1] + 1 === a) {
                last[1] = a;
            } else {
                r.push([a, a]);
            }
            return r;
        }, [])
        .reduce(function (r, a) {
            return r.concat(a[0] === a[1] ? a[0] : a[1] - a[0] < 2 ? a : a.join('-'));
        }, [])
        .join();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Much cleaner.  Thanks Nina!